# Configuring Index text length MySQL in Doctrine

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a text field in my database and a index on it for the first 10 characters. How do I specify that in my Doctrine Entity?

I can't find any information about database specific options for indexes anywhere :/

This is my "partial" MySQL create statement:

```
 KEY `sourceaddr_index` (`sourceaddr`(10)),
```

And this is my @Index in doctrine:

```
 @ORM\Index(name="sourceaddr_index", columns={"sourceaddr"}, options={}),
```

This dosnt interfere with the regular use, but I noticed the problem when deploying development to a new laptop, and creating the database based on my entities...

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: MySQL will index a lot more than 10 characters by default—do you really need to limit it to 10?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've had very good luck naming the index in Doctrine, after manually creating it in MySQL. It's not pretty or elegant, and it's prone to cause errors moving from dev to production if you forget to recreate the index. But, Doctrine seems to understand it respect it.

In my entity, I have the following definition. Doctrine ignores the length option - it's wishful thinking on my part.

```
/**
  * Field
  *
  * @ORM\Table(name="field", indexes={
  *     @ORM\Index(name="field_value_bt", columns={"value"}, options={"length": 100})
  * })
```

And in MySQL, I execute

```
CREATE INDEX field_value_bt  ON field (value(100))
```

As far as I've seen, Doctrine just leaves the index alone so long as it's named the same.

Answer (score 15):

Possible since Doctrine 2.9, see: https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/pull/2412

```
@Index(name="slug", columns={"slug"}, options={"lengths": {191}})
```

Unfortunately, Doctrine seem to be very picky with whitespace location, so e.g. `update --dump-sql` yields:

```
 DROP INDEX slug ON wp_terms;
 CREATE INDEX slug ON wp_terms (slug(191));
```

and even if you execute those, they messages will stay there (tested with MariaDB 10.3.14).

Comment: Also if you want to add this to composite index, it works too `options={"lengths": {191, 191}}` and `options={"lengths": {null, 191}}`

Answer (score 1):

In short: you can't set this within Doctrine. Doctrine's ORM is specifically focused on cross vendor compatability and the type of index you're describing, though supported in many modern RDBMS, is somewhat outside the scope of Doctrine to handle.

Unfortunately there isn't an easy way around this if you use Doctrine's schema updater (in Symfony that would be `php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force`) as if you manually update the database, Doctrine will sometimes, regress that change to keep things in sync.

In instances where I've needed something like this I've just set up a [fixture](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html) that sends the relevant `ALTER TABLE` statement via SQL. If you're going to be distributing your code (i.e. it may run on other/older databases) you can wrap the statement with a [platform check](http://doctrine-dbal.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/platforms.html) to make sure.

It's not ideal but once your app/software stabilises, issues like this shouldn't happen all that often.

Comment: Thanks, thats wery helpful... Any idea what the point of platform-specific options is?

Comment: The platform abstraction that Doctrine uses is good for when you're developing things like DQL extensions. For example, in MySQL you can call `MONTH()` around a date to get the month part, whereas in PGSQL you do `EXTRACT(x FROM y)`, having a platform check lets you do one extension for both vendors. The shorthand is: if you're doing a lot of platform specific things, maybe using a general ORM isn't the best fit.